# I am getting extra margins on the right hand side of my page

Tags: html, css

Please help me in figuring out this problem. For the attached html and css I am getting that extra margin on the right side which I dont need. What changes should I make. Please tell me your suggestions. I am new to web development. Thank you.

What I have already tried is to change the position of hero from relative to fixed and it/remove the extra margin, but that makes my header to cover all the page and the rest content wont show.

Following is my code. 'browser output screenshot' shows that I get unwanted margin or whitespace on the right hand of my page. Scrollbar also becomes scrollable because of this margin. I have marked the margin with a vertical red line. How can I edit my css to remove that margin and make my page unscrollable. Thank you.

[html-screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jV3Jp.png)

[css-screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bbmV.png)

[browser-output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qie0z.png)

Comment: Please add your code as text, not images.

Answer (score -1):

You need to change the `width` of `.hero` from `100%` to `100vw`

& trying not to use `position:relative` in this case

Comment: There's still margin on the right when I do this. I get the margins removed only when I use position: fixed. But using fixed position hides all my content on the back of header/hero including all page.

Comment: you can try   width of video 100vw

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Have you try to put something like that into your css :

`*{ padding: 0;  margin:0; box-sizing: border-box;}`

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
* { overflow: hidden; }
```

If that helps then some container is overflowing, check one by one

Comment: It helped but again when I use this then only header is showing and is fixed all over the page. No other content 'e.g., contents, footer' is shown. I have checked all the code one by one but can't figure out anything that helps. Can you suggest something.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).